# issue with autocomplete

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I'm coding a new website to learn PHP, and coding, and am making an autosuggest that is populated by two mysql tables.

Heres my code (Yes, I'm using mysql, but I'll rewrite this in mysqli once I find a solution!):

suggest.php:

```
require("./config.php");

$q = $_GET['q'];

$names = '';

$result = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM company WHERE name LIKE '$q%' UNION SELECT cat FROM cat WHERE cat LIKE '$q%' UNION SELECT subcat FROM subcat WHERE subcat LIKE '$q%' LIMIT 10"");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { $names .= $row[name]."\n"; }

echo $names;
?>
```

index.php ( where the searchbox is)

```
<form class="form-search span8 offset6">
   <input type="text" id='search' name='q' class="input-medium search-query">
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">GO!</button>
</form>
```

later in index.php (I call jquery.js before):

```
 <script src="public/js/jquery-ui-1.8.22.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"
charset="utf-8"></script>
<script>
    $(function () {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#search").autocomplete("./suggest.php");
        });
    });
</script>
```

The rows I'm trying to populate my autosuggest are the **subcat** row from the **subcat** table, the **name** table from **company** table, and **cat** from **cat** table.

The autosuggest isn't showing up? What's wrong?

Thanks for all help!

Comment: turn on firebug (f12) and see what it says

Comment: You have an extra quote in your SQL query string.  (It also happens to be wide open to SQL injection.)

Comment: @Corbin, thanks for mentioning that!

Comment: at a guess autocomplete is expecting JSON formatted text not raw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try sending JSON formatted data from php, like:

```
$names = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { 
    $names[] = $row['name']; 
}
echo json_encode($names);//format the array into json data
```

Answer (score 2):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

> Expected data format The data from local data, a url or a callback can
>   come in two variants:
>
> ```
> An Array of Strings:
> [ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
> An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
> [ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
> ```

you are just returning the names selected separated by line breaks

Answer (score 1):

from the documentations of jquery autocomplete

http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/

The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:

```
An Array of Strings:
[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]
An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]
```

try to pass your data accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

read the [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote) of jquery ui autocomplete

#### Expected data format

The data from local data, a url or a callback can come in two variants:

- An Array of Strings:
  `[ "Choice1", "Choice2" ]`
- An Array of Objects with label and value properties:
  `[ { label: "Choice1", value: "value1" }, ... ]`

> The label property is displayed in the suggestion menu. The
> value will be inserted into the input element after the user selected
> something from the menu. If just one property is specified, it will be
> used for both, eg. if you provide only value-properties, the value
> will also be used as the label.